# can i use the built in map application to get an address and pass it to my application in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

hey guys i'm new in android and i'm trying to make an application that use maps to get an address(longitude and latitude) of any place or send longitude and latitude to the maps to show an address on it and i'm asking can i make this with the maps built in  application and how

Answer (score 0):

yes you can: Using an intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+currLatatitude+","+currLongitude+");
            startActivity(i);
```

Comment: i think this will pass an address to the maps application?

Comment: It will take latitude & langitude as params. You can search for other options.

Comment: but i want to get the longitude and latitude from the map and pass it to my application how can i do this?

Comment: i want to do both getting and sending addresses from and to the map